# How to automate ctrl+d action in the ssh expect script in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, expect

I have a usecase where I need to execute a command after connecting to the host through ssh. After the command execution, I need to perform Ctrl-D and Ctrl-M so that I can issue other commands.

I tried with using EOF but It is completely closing the session.

```
expect << EOF
spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no LocalCOMUser@$nodeIp -p $ssh_port

expect {
         "password:" {}
          timeout { send_user "Timed out in ssh connection" ;exit 1}
}

send "p@ssword\r"
expect {
         ">" {}
          timeout { send_user "Timed out in ssh connection" ;exit 1}
}

set timeout 120
send "mml\r"
expect {
         "<" {}
          timeout { send_user "Timed out in ssh connection" ;exit 1}
}
send "$command1\r"
expect {
         "<" {}
}
send "exit;\r"
expect {
         ">" {}
          timeout { send_user "Timed out in ssh connection" ;exit 1}
}
send "exit\r"

EOF
```

Need a command that does action as Ctrl-d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simulate pressing Ctrl-D by sending the ^D/<kbd>␄</kbd> character:

```
send "\x04"
```

Comment: Ctrl-M is decimal 13, so hexadecimal d, so `\x0d`, but that's the same as `\r`, which you use already. For more codes, you can consult a table by executing `man ascii` (exit by pressing "q"). Ex.: For Ctrl-X, you find the character X in the right part of the table, then follow the same row to the left to find the Hex code for Ctrl-X; `\x18`.

Comment: Thanks again!  It really helped me.